# Nothing on Ubuntu desktop but Ubuntu color home screen

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, icons, ubuntu-10.10

I've installed Ubuntu 10.04 - my desktop loads up but doesn't have any search icons or system search. I can log in and also right click but that's all. Nothing on the desktop but the Ubuntu color page.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu 10.04 did you install? Is it a clean install? Could you describe your hardware a bit?